# Custom template argument binder to use with with template template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, arguments, bind

I have a template class taking 3 arguments, I need to bind 2 of them before and pass later that binded version to a "Parent" `template template class` I inherit from. 
(I've searched previously asked questions, but none tries to inherit from the parent.)

How could I make it work ?

Here is a sample code :

```
template <template<class> class W, class ...D>
struct Parent{};

template <class B, class T, class ...D>
struct Arg{};

template <class B, class ...D>
struct Bind{
    template <class T>
    using arg = Arg<B, T, D...>;
};

template <class B, class ...D>
struct DD : public Parent<Bind<B, D...>::t, D...> //compiler complains*
{ };

 * template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template.
```

I have tried using `typename` keyword ; and using a `struct` inheriting instead of a `using directive` in the `Binder`, none worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you probably meant `Bind<B, D...>::arg` instead of `Bind<B, D...>::t` in the code snippet.

Secondly, you need the `template` keyword, as `Bind<B, D...>` is a type-dependent *id-expression*. I.e.

```
template <class B, class ...D>
struct DD : public Parent<Bind<B, D...>::template arg, D...>
{ };
```